# CreateProcessAsUser hToken is zero

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, service

I'm creating an app (name AppRunner) that will run an executable (name EXE) using winapi.

In AppRunner, I'm using CreateProcessAsUser in order to run EXE, and this method takes an hToken (a user token).

When AppRunner will be executed by user System in session 0, It will successfully fetch the user token (WTSQueryUserToken with the console session id) and everything will work fine.
However, when AppRunner will be executed by the logged in user in session>0, It will not be able to get the user token.

I noticed that when calling CreateProcessAsUser with hToken=0, EXE is being executed under the logged in user in the user's session (>0).

**Can I assume that calling CreateProcessAsUser with hToken = 0 will execute EXE under the logged in user in the user's session**? I didn't find any documentation about it in the CreateProcessAsUser page.

Thanks

Comment: `CreateProcessAsUser` with *hToken = 0* have the same effect as `CreateProcess`  - new process will be executed with current process token

Comment: BTW, in case anyone else encounter this: CreateProcessAsUser with hToken=0 will indeed create a process with the same user as the user of the current process, BUT, CreateEnvironmentBlock will create an environment with default values, which means that appdata folder for example will point to the default user and not the current user's appdata folder. This is a big issue for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BTW, in case anyone else encounter this: CreateProcessAsUser with
>   hToken=0 will indeed create a process with the same user as the user
>   of the current process, **BUT, CreateEnvironmentBlock will create an
>   environment with default values, which means that appdata folder for
>   example will point to the default user and not the current user's
>   appdata folder.** This is a big issue for me

Two workarounds:

1. Inherit parent process' (AppRunner) environment when calling [`CreateEnvironmentBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-createenvironmentblock). Then `APPDATA` environment variable will point to the current user's appdata folder. But `USERPROFILE` still point to `C:\Users\Default`.
2. Acquire parent process' (AppRunner) token using [`GetCurrentProcessToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocesstoken), then pass this token to `CreateEnvironmentBlock`. Then `APPDATA` and `USERPROFILE` environment variable both point to current user.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however my solution is:   
when AppRunner is running in session 0 I use CreateProcessAsUser.  
when AppRunner is running in session > 0  (so no System user therefor I can't extract the hToken) I use Process.Start.  
Do you think your solution is better? I'm not sure what are the differences between the 2 process running methods

Comment: @Alonzzo2 I just answer your question quoted in my answer. Feel free post your solution as answer.